# How do I resize a figure window to cover the entire screen on MATLAB 2014 (b) +?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want my entire screen, say X by Y resolution, to be covered with an image of X by Y resolution on MATLAB 2014(b)+ platforms. In the previous versions, WindowAPI [1] seemed to work well with the following command. Basically I need to display my image on full screen mode in the said monitor.

```
iptsetpref('ImshowBorder','tight');
WindowAPI(Fig_Handle, 'Position', 'Full')
```

Due to version changes/improvements, this method doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

[1] - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi

This is not a duplicate question. All methods mentioned there do not work.

Comment: If you tried a bunch of methods that didn't work, explain what went wrong. You were probably close on at least one of them, and sharing what failed may allow someone to quickly help you fix it.

Comment: Sure.

I also found a working solution. While I am not sure what the problem is, I suspect that figure management has changed in MATLAB 14(b) +. I ended up using http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11112-fullscreen ; which works great.

Comment: Me too I'm trying to solve the same problem: to show an image full screen without any window borders, menus etc... exactly as it is possible with the 'To video display' block on Simulink. It has the option 'Full Screen (Esc to exit)'. Is there a possibility with Matlab? Thanks